# understanding ifelse with NAs

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I can nest multiple `ifelse` statements as follows:

```
ifelse(2==1, "2==1", ifelse(3==1, "3==1", ifelse(1==1, "1==1", NA)))
#[1] "1==1"
```

However, it seems as if NAs are getting into the way. The following returns ...

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA ,NA),
                 b = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA),
                 c = c(rep(NA, 4), 1, 1))
ifelse(df$a==1, "a==1", ifelse(df$b==1, "b==1", ifelse(df$c==1, "c==1", NA)))
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" NA     NA     NA     NA
```

... instead of the desired

```
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1"  "c==1" "c==1"
```

I could first assign different values to NAs to obtain the desired result:

```
df_noNA <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2 ,2),
                 b = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 c = c(rep(2, 4), 1, 1))

ifelse(df_noNA$a==1, "a==1", ifelse(df_noNA$b==1, "b==1", ifelse(df_noNA$c==1, "c==1", NA)))
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1"  "c==1" "c==1"
```

However, I was wondering if there was a more direct way to tell `ifelse` to ignore NAs?

---

**EDIT**: I am looking for an efficient solution to this problem.

As noted in the comments by @Cath, I can tell ´ifelse´ to ignore NAs:

```
ifelse(df$a==1 &  !is.na(df$a), "a==1", 
    ifelse(df$b==1 & !is.na(df$b), "b==1", 
        ifelse(df$c==1 & !is.na(df$c), "c==1", NA)))
```

However, as also noted by @akrun, it seems somewhat lengthy to type `!is.na(x_i)` for every column (personally it also seems redundant to me to specify that x should equal 1 and not be NA). At this moment, the workaround of first replacing NAs with a value that is not present in the data set (e.g., 2 in this case) and then writing an ´ifelse´ statement without `!is.na(x_i)` seems more efficient.

Comment: `R` cannot know if `NA` fulfill the condition or not, you need to add a missing value check with `is.na` to make it work properly

Comment: @Cath it can be done in efficient ways and by duping you are denying the OP to get good answers

Comment: thanks, that was helpful: `ifelse(df$a==1 &  !is.na(df$a), "a==1", ifelse(df$b==1 & !is.na(df$b), "b==1", ifelse(df$c==1 & !is.na(df$c), "c==1", NA))) works`. However, it seems somewhat verbose to me to indicate that as a test x should be equal to 1 and not equal to NA...

Comment: @Cath I am opening this as the OP's question is different and need efficient ways

Comment: the question is about the error and not about efficiency. Don't change the Q so you can put an answer

Comment: @Cath Please read the OP's comments  `However, it seems somewhat verbose to me to indicate that as a test x should be equal to 1 and not equal to NA...`

Comment: @Cath Are you saying that if the OP had 100 columns, he should use `100` ifelse statements

Comment: @Cath, I found your contribution helpful because it pointed me to another way to solve my problem. However, I do find your solution lengthier than my workaround of replacing all NA entries with e.g., 99999 first. I am still wondering if there was a more efficient way of telling ifelse to ignore NAs

Comment: @Flo Could you update your post with the one in the comments

Comment: @Flo as akrun said, then you can update your post or post another question. This one is about the surprising result your were getting and is a dupe of other questions.

Comment: @akrun, will do!

Comment: @Flo Please update the expected output for `df_noNA`

Comment: @Jaap You are abusing your dupe hammer power by tagging it to some posts while the OP's question is also about efficiency

Comment: @akrun, also updating the expected output for df_nonNA now